# Searching for surprising equation connecting distant mathematical fields

Tags: reference-request

I hope this is not too off topic on this site, if so i excuse myself.

Some time ago i read an article about important **equations** (as most lists feature prominent unequations) in math and the unsolved problems they represent. Among them were a simple arithmetical calculation of form $$4567+1=4568$$ (sadly i can't remember the actual numbers), where the former number represents, if i recall correctly, the order of a finite group and the latter is a quantity from some very unrelated mathematical branch. This connection was said to be discovered accidentally by an mathematician couple and rather surprising.

I would be really thankfull for any hint where to find the publication in question or more on this topic.

Comment: McKay's Monstrous Moonshine observation is 196884 = 196883 + 1.  See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monstrous_moonshine

Comment: @S.Carnahan post this as an answer, using those values i found the [article in question](http://tonysmaths.blogspot.co.uk/2013/05/my-favorite-equation.html) in matter of a minute.

Comment: The equation $4372 = 4371 + 1$ gives generalized moonshine for the Baby monster - experimentally worked out by Larissa Queen in 1980, and proved by Gerald Höhn in 2003 (still unpublished).